# How to delete Postgres on Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos

I deleted postgres on my my. However the "postgres" user is not gone.
I tried with

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/postgresql/
sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/
```

I don't know why PostgreSQL still appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

`sudo userdel -f PostgreSQL`

**UPDATE**

1. List all User Accounts

`$ /usr/bin/dscl . -list /Users`

2. Follow the command to Delete a User Account

`$ sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/<USER_ACCOUNT>`

Example:

`$ sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/PostgreSQL`

3. List all User Accounts

`$ /usr/bin/dscl . -list /Users`

Comment: I get this:
sudo: userdel: command not found

Comment: Check my update